# How to get the time taken by hiveQL scripts

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop, hive

I have set of hive queries and running that as a job.
for example : hive1.hql,hive2.hql,hive3.hql
while running i need to write each file name with time taken by queries written in .hql.
output should be like

hive1.hql  30 sec

hive2.hql  22 sec

hive3.sql  11 sec

How can i achieve this with HIVE & SHELL scripts.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code.

(Please note this code might need some changes as per your need)

```
#########################################################################
#############################  DRAFT SCRIPT   ########################
### HEADER - PROGRAM NAME - <Temp.sh>                                   
#########################################################################
#########################################################################
##################################
###DEFINING THE LOCAL VARIABLES###
##################################

DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

LOGFILE="/home/LOG/"$DATE".log"

echo "Executing hive script " >> $LOGFILE

START=$(date +%s);

hive -f /home/HIVE/hive1.hql

END=$(date +%s);
echo "hive1.hql" 

echo $((END-START)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'

echo "Hive1 process is done";

START1=$(date +%s);

hive -f /home/HIVE/hive2.hql

END1=$(date +%s);

echo "hive2.hql" 

echo $((END1-START1)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'

echo "Hive2 process is done";

exit;
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhavesh